# DEVgrants program still alive?

Tags: ether, dapp-development, ethereum-wallet-dapp

is the DEVgrants program to promote the development of ethereum dapps still alive ?

https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/04/07/devgrants-help/

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering this today. (January 2017.)

A [post](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/01/08/d%CE%BEvgrants-update-new-funding/) on the official Ethereum blog last January outlined who had been given the first set of grants. Those funds must surely have been used up by now.

The webpage that they mentioned they were to build last year doesn't seem to have come into existence yet, and their [Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/devgrants/public) has been quiet since August 2016.

Having said all that, their Twitter [feed](https://twitter.com/devgrants?lang=en) is still active...